# Why won't my rows merge, even though my variables are identical?

Tags: r, join, merge, duplicates, row

I have two very basic data sets, [GVA](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rCVRa4Lpy06BW9aFNi9_0aDdfWd7kqeY/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=100945010387295658977&rtpof=true&sd=true) and [Comptroller](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Fn_VH7W1Q6TVoDoKgKakMdco6NrsT0wtI56udVR0SL0/edit#gid=1981344428), that I am trying to merge based on Address and Participant Age Group, but the observations aren't actually being joined. I want Participant Names from GVA with the details from the other.

`newmerge<-merge(Philadelphia_PA_Nonfatal_Shootings_Sheet_Jan_1_Sept_30_2021, export_89ce5a4e_f66a_4a10_8fdd_ee778a7e3d66, by=c("Address", "Participant Age Group"), all=TRUE)`

This is what I get Results after Merge with Unmatched Rows:

[image: Results after Merge with Unmatched Rows]
I have checked that my variables are both character format, along with other commong troubleshoots from this sight, so any advice is welcome.

Comment: Please provide a minimal example with data & code. You can post your data with `dput()`

Comment: add some relevant sample data using `dput()`.. (i.e.: no images!)

Comment: Agree with MKR and Wimpel. By the way, this is the longest and most complicated names for data frames I have ever seen.

Comment: [This](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) is why posting data as images is *very* unhelpful.  We need to see both `Philadelphia_PA_Nonfatal_Shootings_Sheet_Jan_1_Sept_30_2021` and `export_89ce5a4e_f66a_4a10_8fdd_ee778a7e3d66`.  (As @www wrote - Wow, just wow!)  Oh, and welcome to SO!  PS:  If you're certain everything is character, the first thing I'd check for is leading and trailing whitespace.

Comment: Thanks all, I tried linking to data sets as google sheets/hyperlinks. I will try dput in the future

Answer (score 0):

The obvious has been pointed out already. Don't use images to show your data.

The reason why some rows are not merging is because `merge()` is case-sensitive. One way of solving it is by doing `toupper` or `tolower` on the columns you want to merge on but an alternative method that might be a bit cleaner is using the package `fuzzyjoin`:

```
fuzzyjoin::stringdist_join(Philadelphia_PA_Nonfatal_Shootings_Sheet_Jan_1_Sept_30_2021, 
                           export_89ce5a4e_f66a_4a10_8fdd_ee778a7e3d66, 
                           by = c("Address", "Participant Age Group"), 
                           max_dist = 0, mode = "full", ignore_case = T)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! I tried removing spaces but of course its case sensitive, silly me. I am teaching myself R as we speak (obviously).
I also understand I should not only put images, but I made my data publicly available through hyperlinks, I had thought. Was that not accessible?

Comment: It depends. For example your hyperlinks lead to excel sheets and not to dataframes or datatables. One of the tables doesn't have headers also so obviously some steps had to be taken by you to import this data correctly into R. What is the point to let the respondents re-invent the wheel when you already have two dataframes imported? It's courtesy more than anything